# UNIX shell to move files from one folder to another folder

Tags: shell, unix

```
  #!/bin/bash

export folder=`date -d "today - 1 days" '+%Y%m%d'`;

if filename in /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A; then

result=

if filename = *$folder*; then

result= mv $filename /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A/test

else

if filename = *$folder*; then

result= mv $filename /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A/test

elif

done;
```

Hi..I'm trying to execute the above scrpot but it is throwing the exception as ./test1.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

```
./test1.sh: line 11: `done'
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: You should run this through http://www.shellcheck.net/ first - it will help you fixing a bunch of issues. Then, if you still have problems, you should come back and ask a question about these specific issues.

Comment: Hi I tried the a script in shellcheck.net but i got the below exception  #!/bin/bash
export date=`date -d "today - 1 days" '+%Y%m%d'`;
echo "mv *"$date"* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test"
exception:++ date -d 'today - 1 days' +%Y%m%d
+ export date=20161226
+ date=20161226
+ echo 'mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test'
mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test

Answer (score 1):

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]...
[ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

Bash `if` statements end in `fi`

Comment: Hi I tried the a script  but i got the below exception  #!/bin/bash
export date=`date -d "today - 1 days" '+%Y%m%d'`;
echo "mv *"$date"* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test"
exception:++ date -d 'today - 1 days' +%Y%m%d
+ export date=20161226
+ date=20161226
+ echo 'mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test'
mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test....can you please help

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the `ìf` `elif` statement that way, according to the structure of your program this should be looking something like :

```
export folder=`date -d "today - 1 days" '+%Y%m%d'`;
if filename in /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A; then
    result= something_here
elif filename = *$folder*; then

    result= mv $filename /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A/test

elif filename = *$folder*; then
    result= mv $filename /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A/test

else
    result = PUT here the last condition

fi
```

Comment: cool mate, if it helps please accept the answer elif post errors for further assistance

Comment: HI Nishant..Thanks for your response..Let me clearly mention what the requirement..im trying to movie all files of yesterday to another folder.my main folder is /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A and if ther is any files of yesterday then i need to movie that file to /r1/test/med_sms/FDA3A/test
.can you please help on this..Also i tried your suggestion and i got this exception     ./test2.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./test2.sh: line 14: `fi'

Comment: HI Nishanth..I tried the below script but not able to execute.can you please help #!/bin/bash
export date=`date -d "today - 1 days" '+%Y%m%d'`;
echo "mv *"$date"* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test"

Comment: it gave the below exception     ++ date -d 'today - 1 days' +%Y%m%d
+ export date=20161226
+ date=20161226
+ echo 'mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test'
mv *20161226* rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A rocra_directory/rocra_polled/med_sms/FDA3A/test@Nishanth SIngh